# Scrollbars when there should not be any?

Tags: overflow, scrollbars

I have set scrollbars to auto, but still they do appear, although the website's content is minimal. I just can not see, what is wrong here.

CSS code:

```
html {height: 100%; overflow: auto; margin: 0;}
body {background: url(random_img.php) no-repeat top left fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover; background-attachment: fixed; margin: 0; height: 100%; font-size: 1rem; font-family: Cabin, Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;}
#stage {margin: 2% auto 0 auto; padding: 0; min-height: 100%; width: 58.75rem;}
```

Example website: ivanschneider.com

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to remove height: 100% from html.